# Using Xamarin Forms with Firebase messaging, why is OnTokenRefresh() not triggering?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm writing an app with the intent of using Azure Notification Hubs.  I've been following several of the online [examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/xamarin-notification-hubs-push-notifications-android-gcm) to get the Android assembly wired up first.  The only difference is the name of my classes, for example I use FirebaseIIDService instead of "MyFirebaseIIDService" or whatever.  It derives from FirebaseInstanceIdService and has the attributes shown in the examples:

```
[Service]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" })]
```

My override of OnTokenRefresh() is never called.  In MainActivity.OnCreate() my Intent.Extras is NULL (I'm assuming it should contain the Intents for messaging, but perhaps that's incorrect.)

The google-services.json is there, the Android Manifest has been updated:

```
<receiver
      android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver"
      android:exported="false" />

    <receiver
      android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver"
      android:exported="true"
      android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
        <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

I swear this was working at one point.  What could possibly be wrong?  Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

So reading more about this, it appears this section of code is only hit when the application is installed, or if the token is invalidated.  You can put a block of code inside your MainActivity.OnCreate() method to invalidate the token.  This triggers a refresh.  Example:

```
#if DEBUG  
        Task.Run(() =>
        {               
            FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.DeleteInstanceId();
            Log.Debug(TAG, "Forced token: " + FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.Token);
        });
#endif
```